# calc (100% - 300px) working on Safari not of Firefox or Chrome

Tags: html, css, safari

This is my HTML/CSS:

```css
#all {
  text-align: center;
}
.photo_img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px);
  max-height: -moz-calc(100% - 300px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 300px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/ed8f597aae5d145a51a13a7eaddac58e/tumblr_nlh3w0m4GS1u4c0gpo1_1280.jpg" class="photo_img">
</div>
```

I don't know why it works only on Safari.
Can you please help me making it cross-browser?

https://jsfiddle.net/q3fwavq5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a percentage based height of `100%`. The height of the `.photo_img` element determines the height of the parent element (since it's the only child) which render percentage based units useless because they aren't relative to anything. To solve this, you would need to set the parent element's height in percentages too. In doing so, `.photo_img` can have a max height of `calc(100% - 300px)` *relative* to the parent elements.

You could set the `html`/`body`/`#all` elements to have a height of `100%`.. (a fixed height on just `#all` would work as well).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/q8hrk1tp/)

```
html, body, #all {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [viewport-relative units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) rather than percentage based units. In doing so, the height is based on `100%` of the viewport (rather than the direct containing parent element).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2m1uLfaw/)

```
.photo_img {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
}
```